# Express JS access remotely

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js

I have an app set up using BackboneJS, NodeJS and ExpressJS.  I have trouble accessing my routes from my application.  But I can access my routes directly in my browser and see the output.

For example this works:

`http://test.myserver.com:3000/employees/1`
 (where `test.myserver.com` is my server address accessible externally)

My express server declaration is as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
    employee = require('./routes/employees');

var app = express();

app.get('/employees/:id', employee.findById);

app.listen(3000);
```

My problem is that when I try to access the route through my application I get an access error.

`http://test.myserver.com/pages/index.html#employees/1`

```
GET http://localhost:3000/employees/1?callback=jQuery19107984810129273683_1457829695460&_=1457829695461 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can I access my routes from within my application using Express?

Comment: You need to either request from the same oriin as jfriend mentioned in his answer, or you need to enable cross origin requests on your node server.

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue.  You say you're loading a web page at:

```
http://test.myserver.com/pages/index.html#employees/1
```

But, the URL request is for:

```
http://localhost:3000/employees/1?callback=jQuery19107984810129273683_1457829695460&_=1457829695461
```

Those are different domains and different ports.  It looks to me like jQuery sees that this is a cross origin request and is trying to turn it into a JSONP request, but your server is not support JSONP.

Likely what you need to do is to get the Javascript in your web page to be requesting the SAME origin (same domain, same port) that the web page is loaded from.  Then, it will not be cross origin request and it should work (if nothing else is wrong).

Please show us the relevant Javascript in your web page that is making this request so we can advise more specifically on how to fix it.

Also, if you're expecting your node.js server to serve your web pages, you will need node.js code to do that (you don't show any of that code) since node.js does not serve any pages by default (unlike some other web servers).

Comment: Here is my code that triggers the redirect: `getSearch: function() {
        var key = $('#searchText').val();
        this.searchResults.fetch({reset: true, data: {name: key}});
        var self = this;
        alert(key);
        directory.router.navigate("employees/1", true);
   },`

Comment: I essentially have a search function in my shell view that has a search box.  When a user inputs a value for an employee, I want to redirect them to the employee/:id route with the employee id entered.  I know my routes work fine when I pass in values manually as I explained above.  But with backbonejs I'm not sure how to call my route with the id from the textbox passed in.